# How to end libsoundio stream after starting?

Tags: c++, audio

I've built and ran the example at [libsound.io](http://libsound.io/).

The life cycle of `SoundIoOutStream* outstream` is not clear for me.

According to the example `soundio_outstream_create(device)` returns that pointer. Then `soundio_outstream_open(outstream)` and `soundio_outstream_start(outstream)` gets called. At this point the callback starts getting called.

Is there any way to stop the callback from getting called?

Is there any soundio function to "close" or "stop" `outstream`?

(I may edit or add to my questions based on the responses, right now I have too many unknowns to ask the right question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important thing is that: we don't create a stream for each sound clip in the resources, we create a stream each time we want to play a sound clip.

After playing the sound clip, `soundio_outstream_destroy(outstream);` stops the callback from getting called. The trick is that we can't call this function within `write_callback` so we should implement some kind of messaging between callback thread and our app's thread to destroy `outstream`.

There are more details in my answer here: [Play multiple streams with soundio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64001616/how-to-play-more-than-one-stream-at-once-using-soundio/64399208#64399208)